# Problems creating JSON file with javax createObjectBuilder

Tags: java, json

I am trying to teach myself how to work with JSON but I am having trouble building a JSON object in Java. I am importing javax.json and trying to create something like this:

```
  JsonObject model = Json.createObjectBuilder()
            .add("firstName", "Duke")
            .add("lastName", "Java")
            .add("age", 18)
            .build();
```

I get this error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.json.spi.JsonProvider.createObjectBuilder()Ljavax/json/JsonObjectBuilder;
    at javax.json.Json.createObjectBuilder(Json.java:266)
    at com.example.jsontest.Test.main(Test.java:15)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You're attempting to use the `javax.json` interfaces without a provider.

Comment: Can you tell me how to add a provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First learn pure JSON, without trying to use a "model" or convert Java objects to JSON or whatever.  Create the appropriate Maps and Lists and use something like [json-simple](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) to "serialize" the Maps/Lists into a JSON string.

Once you understand how simple JSON really is, it's easier to understand and use the complicated kluges that so many Java folks insist on using to handle JSON.

Comment: Thanks so much! This was extremely helpful and easy to understand. I was really getting lost in the other components that were needed to get started with JSON. This library worked as expected immediately!

Answer (score 2):

You're attempting to use the new `javax.json` API without a JSON provider. To my knowledge (and some googling) the only one at the moment is the [reference implementation from glassfish](https://jsonp.java.net/download.html).

In your pom.xml you would need both dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: If you're not using maven to manage your dependencies/project then you need to go and download the actual .jar from the link in the answer (I updated it with the link)